# Using iscmdbld.exe to build not working with Start /wait

Tags: batch-file, cmd, installshield

I am trying to build an installshield installer via a batch script via the command

```
START /wait "C:\Program Files (x86)\InstallShield\2012Spring\System\IsCmdBld.exe" -p "installer path.ism" -r Release > ".txt to hold output"
```

it works fine when I use CALL instead of START /wait

when I use START /wait I get an error saying "Windows cannot find '-p'. make sure you typed the name correctly, and try again"

I sometime have multiple installers being built with the same batch script so i want it to wait to finish building one before it starts the next one which is why I am trying to use START /wait

Comment: perhaps `START "" /wait "<your path...>"` could work because `START` might interpret the first quoted argument as the window title

Answer (score 0):

```
START "" /wait "C:\Program Files (x86)\InstallShield\2012Spring\System\IsCmdBld.exe" -p "installer path.ism" -r Release > ".txt to hold output"
```

As per `START` docs: [Start a program, command or batch script (opens in a new window.)](http://ss64.com/nt/start.html)

> ```
> Syntax
>       START "title" [/D path] [options] "command" [parameters]
>
> Key:
>    title       Text for the CMD window title bar (required.)
>    path        Starting directory.
>    command     The command, batch file or executable program to run.
>    parameters  The parameters passed to the command.
> ```
>
> Always include a TITLE this can be a simple string like "My Script" or
>   just a pair of empty quotes "". According to the Microsoft
>   documentation, the title is optional, but depending on the other
>   options chosen you can have problems if it is omitted.

Answer (score 0):

Go the easy route, just list sequential iscmdbld commands in your batch file:

```
set ISCMDBLD="C:\Program Files (x86)\InstallShield\2012Spring\System\IsCmdBld.exe"
%ISCMDBLD% -p "installer1 path.ism" -r Release1 > ".txt1 to hold output"
%ISCMDBLD% -p "installer2 path.ism" -r Release2 > ".txt2 to hold output"
...
```

Since iscmdbld is a console application, the standard behavior in a batch file should be for it to block until the application exits. Typically `start /wait` is only relevant for gui applications.